# Input Field Doesnot Appear

Tags: python, django

so here is my Code form.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category


class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
  # class Meta:
  #    model = Category
  #    fields = ('title',)
title = forms.CharField(label = 'title', max_length=100)
```

here is My view.py :

```
def CategoryForm(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = CategroyForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         # category = form.save(commit = False)
         # category.title = post
         # category.save()
         return redirect('posts/create_blog.html')
 else:
    form = CategoryForm()
    template = 'posts/create_blog.html'
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,template,context)
```

and here is my view.py :

```
      <form action= "CategoryForm" method = "POST" style = 'margin-top:0'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!--<label style='margin-left: 4%; color: gray;'>Choose Category Name</label>-->

                  {{ form.as_p }}

                <input type = 'submit' value='Submit'>

            </form>
```

I dont really understand whats th eproblenm inputs are not appear

my model.py :

```
class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


def __str__(self):
    self.title
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors just input doesnot appears

Comment: In form.py is the last line indented properly? Here, the indentation looks incorrect.

Comment: yes its last line  its not right i  did it  from documentation :/

Comment: There is one strange thing   in web pace while i am doin inspect  input is there but  its type is hidden why i have no idea

Comment: @AlexTsirikidze what is your model's definition ? Could it be that it has `editable=False` for the `title` field ?

Comment: I did edit  U can see model.py i think there is not something like that